# how to make jboss wildfly to run on port 80

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

I want to make jboss wildfly to run on default port. Where can i change configuration.

I have changed in standalone-full.xml, even also jboss is not starting.

Comment: What did you change? Did JBoss start before you made the change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the default WildFly standalone profile (i.e. if you don't specify `-c` parameter). Then the configuration from `standalone.xml` is used.

### Command line - argument of standalone script

The simplest way how to change HTTP port is to provide value to `jboss.http.port` system property. You can do it simply by using `-D` argument of `standalone` startup script:

```sh
${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/standalone.sh -Djboss.http.port=80
```

### JBoss CLI tool

Other way is to set it by using JBoss CLI configuration tool:

```sh
# start the WildFly server before running following line (JBoss CLI)
${WILDFLY_HOME}/bin/jboss-cli.sh -c
```

In the CLI tool use following commands:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:write-attribute(name=port,value=80)
:reload
```

Now configuration is stored in the `standalone.xml` and your server is running on port 80.

### Edit standalone.xml file

You can also avoid using JBoss CLI tool and if your server is not running edit the `standalone.xml` configuration file yourself.

Edit the **http** named socket-binding value under "standard-sockets" socket-binding-group. So the new value can look like:

```xml
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:80}"/>
```